# How to assign a schema to ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

According to http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html I should be able to add a SCHEMA to my connection string to override the default "dbo" schema:

> SCHEMA: Set name of schema for new table. If this parameter is not
>   supported the default schema "dbo" is used.

But it does not seem to have any effect and I cannot find an example of how it should be done:

```
call ogr2ogr -overwrite -skipfailures -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=myserver;database=mydb;trusted_connection=yes;SCHEMA=geoserver;" "C:\temp\MapVegas860\Buildings.shp"
```

How to import the shapefile into a 'geoserver' schema?

Comment: By reading the document "schema" is a layer creation option. Add -lco schema=geoserver into your ogr2ogr command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`SCHEMA` is a "layer creation option", specified with the `-lco` parameter.  This should do the trick (split into multiple lines here for readability):

```
call ogr2ogr -overwrite -skipfailures -f MSSQLSpatial
    -lco SCHEMA=geoserver
    "MSSQL:server=myserver;database=mydb;trusted_connection=yes;"
    "C:\temp\MapVegas860\Buildings.shp"
```

Comment: Yes, I was not understanding the documentation.  Here is the fully working configuration I was looking for:

`ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=myserver;database=mydb;trusted_connection=yes;" -lco SCHEMA=geoserver -lco fid=fid -lco geom_name=geom -lco overwrite=yes "myshapefile.shp"`