# Set schema in ogr2ogr from GML to pgdump

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

My ogr2ogr tranformation from a GML to a pgdump sql file always by default uses the schema public. I would like to use a different schema. It seems to be possible: [How to assign a schema to ogr2ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234025/how-to-assign-a-schema-to-ogr2ogr). However in my dump file every line still states the public schema.

This is the code that does run but has the output with still the public schema:

```
ogr2ogr -f PGDump file.sql gi*.xml -oo GML_ATTRIBUTES_TO_OGR_FIELDS=YES -lco SCHEMA=klicbestanden_in
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me with GDAL 2.4.0 from OSGeo4W.

Command:

```
ogr2ogr -f PGDump file.sql foo.jml -lco SCHEMA=klicbestanden_in
```

Result:

```
SET standard_conforming_strings = OFF;
CREATE SCHEMA "klicbestanden_in";
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "klicbestanden_in"."foo" CASCADE;
DELETE FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name = 'foo' AND f_table_schema = 'klicbestanden_in';
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "klicbestanden_in"."foo" ( "ogc_fid" SERIAL, CONSTRAINT "foo_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("ogc_fid") );
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('klicbestanden_in','foo','wkb_geometry',-1,'GEOMETRY',2);
CREATE INDEX "foo_wkb_geometry_geom_idx" ON "klicbestanden_in"."foo" USING GIST ("wkb_geometry");
INSERT INTO "klicbestanden_in"."foo" ("wkb_geometry" ) VALUES ('0102000000070000000000000000C087400000000000E07A40C0DC4433480588400000000000907A40C0DC4433480588400000000000F079400000000000C087400000000000A079404023BBCCB77A87400000000000F079404023BBCCB77A87400000000000907A400000000000C087400000000000E07A40');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I copied your code exactly and it also worked for me. Any idea why the line in my question did not work? Seems to be doing exactly the same?

Comment: No idea, I made a few more tests by copy-pasting your code and it still works OK. There does not seem to be any characters from some odd character set in the command line and having -oo GML_ATTRIBUTES_TO_OGR_FIELDS=YES does not make harm.