# Make ogr2ogr import data to PostGIS using a schema different than public

Tags: ogr2ogr

I've successfully imported from SpatiaLite to PostGIS with the following command:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=mydb" -nlt GEOMETRY input.sqlite
```

However, when I try to use the following command to import it inside a specific schema:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=user password=password dbname=mydb" -nlt GEOMETRY -lco SCHEMA=my_schema input.sqlite
```

It doesn't work... I just see the warning `Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is being appended to.` . But when I check inside PostgreSQL there's no table inside `my_schema`... While after the first command my table goes inside the `public` schema. What is wrong with the last command? Why it's not importing the data inside `my_schema`?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234025/how-to-assign-a-schema-to-ogr2ogr

Comment: @Mapperz It's from that question that I got the `-lco SCHEMA=my_schema` syntax...  My second command is using it... But it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pg.html

> SCHEMA: Set name of schema for new table. Using the same layer name in
> different schemas is supported, **but not in the public schema and
> others**.

If you have the table already in public schema you must rename the table for my_schema with `-nln`.

Comment: Cool, my mistake then was that I executed the first command importing it into the public schema first. Both renaming the layer on the new schema or excluding the table from public works fine.